# Getting an error trying to access element in Pandas series

Tags: python, datetime, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to do something very simple:

```
last_id = len(bg_dt['time']) - 1
last_time = insight_date_to
if last_id >  0:
    print("last_id is %d"%last_id)
    print(bg_dt['time'])
    print(type(bg_dt['time']))
    print(type(last_id))
    print(bg_dt['time'][0])
    last_time = bg_dt['time'][last_id]
```

This produces the following output:

```
Name: time, dtype: datetime64[ns]
<class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>
<class 'int'>
```

> KeyError: 0

**What's going on here?** Here's what I have verified:

- I am using an int as an index
- I am trying to use `[]` with a series
- I am not going out of bounds

As par as details go, I'm on Python 3 and running this on a Jupyter notebook.

Here are examples of `bg['time']`:

```
442751   2016-04-26 09:00:00
445544   2016-04-26 18:00:00
445539   2016-04-27 09:00:00
450923   2016-04-27 18:00:00
450922   2016-04-28 09:00:00
474301   2016-04-29 18:00:00
474298   2016-04-30 09:00:00
474300   2016-04-30 09:00:00
474299   2016-04-30 18:00:00
```

And here is `insight_date_to`, a datetime object, `2016-05-01 00:00:00`.

Comment: Can you add sample of column `bg_dt['time']`?

Comment: @jezrael Thanks for taking a look. I posted a sample.

Comment: But I have problem  - what is `insight_date_to` ?

Comment: @jezrael I'll add in the main body, but here it is, a datetime object, 2016-05-01 00:00:00

Comment: Your sample data doesn't have a 0 as an index value, so the `KeyError` is a valid error message for the sample data.  If 0 is not an index value in your entire dataset, then you are going out of bounds, as you're trying to access an index value that doesn't exist.

Answer (score 3):

I think better is use [`iloc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html), as pointed [conner.xyz](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37146810/getting-an-error-trying-to-access-element-in-pandas-series#comment61832448_37147146) for selecting first value with `0` and last with `-1`:

```
print bg_dt
                      time
442751 2016-04-26 09:00:00
445544 2016-04-26 18:00:00
445539 2016-04-27 09:00:00
450923 2016-04-27 18:00:00
450922 2016-04-28 09:00:00
474301 2016-04-29 18:00:00
474298 2016-04-30 09:00:00
474300 2016-04-30 09:00:00
474299 2016-04-30 18:00:00

print(bg_dt.iloc[0].time)
print(bg_dt.iloc[-1,:].time)
2016-04-26 09:00:00
2016-04-30 18:00:00
```

Or:

```
print(bg_dt.time.iloc[0])
print(bg_dt.time.iloc[-1])
2016-04-26 09:00:00
2016-04-30 18:00:00
```

For checking `DataFrame` is [`empty`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.empty.html):

```
bg_dt = pd.DataFrame()

if not bg_dt.empty:

    print(bg_dt.iloc[0].time)
    print(bg_dt.iloc[-1,:].time)

    print(bg_dt.time.iloc[0])
    print(bg_dt.time.iloc[-1])
```

Comment: I was just about to post this... `.iloc` may also fit the bill